# Kinect Xbox360 + Beaglebone Black + ROS

Tags: ros, kinect, beagleboneblack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to capture the depth and rgb images using kinect xbox360 with beaglebone black using ROS packages. I have so far been successful in doing so on my laptop, using the openni_launch package. But I cannot make it happen in the same way on Beaglebone Black. What shall I have to do differently to get this thing working?
I am kind of new to ROS. So can you please help me out? Is it at all possible to run the kinect with beaglebone black? I found many people are saying that It cannot be done. But why? I also found some videos of kinect working with Beagleboard-xM. Why does it not work with Beaglebone black then?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.
-- Arindam.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237590/kinect-xbox360-+-beaglebone-black-+-ros/) by [abhanjac](https://answers.ros.org/users/27211/abhanjac/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you can try http://wiki.ros.org/freenect_launch
this  is an substitute of openni and work almost like it.

---

Originally posted by [ghaith](https://answers.ros.org/users/26984/ghaith/) with karma: 89 on 2016-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abhanjac](https://answers.ros.org/users/27211/abhanjac/) on 2016-06-20**:
I tried that too... But had same result... Is it at all possible to run the kinect with beaglebone black? I could not find anyone doing it. People used beagleboard-xM but not beaglebone black..

**Comment by [ghaith](https://answers.ros.org/users/26984/ghaith/) on 2016-06-21**:
i am really don't know . just i know openni  don't work any more with indigo and the newest version
and u need to use freenect.